# Not able to get specific value from Json file using python

Tags: python, json, list, extract

I'm having difficulty to get some data from my json file. I'm able to get some of the data but when I want to dig more in details I'm getting error and stuck no where.

Running the script below return an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I know its a list but I'm not sure how to get the rest of the object list.

Script

```
ifile=open('source.json', 'r')
ofile=open('extract.json', 'w')
json_decode=json.load(ifile)
myresult=[]
for item in json_decode:
    mydict={}
    mydict['sID']=item.get('Ls id')
    my_dict['dID']=item.get('items').get('Link ID').get('Metric').get('Link Type')
    mydict['type']=item.get('Type')
    myresult.append(mydict)
myjson=json.dumps(myresult, ofile)
ofile.write(myjson)
ofile.close()
```

source Json file

```
[
  {
    "Ls age": "201",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.2",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.4",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "192.168.100.34"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "192.168.100.33",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "192.168.100.53"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "84",
    "Ls id": "1.1.1.2",
    "Adv rtr": "1.1.1.2",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Link count": "5"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "1699",
    "seq#": "80008d72",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.1",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.1",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "12",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.3",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "192.168.100.26"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "192.168.100.25",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.2",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "192.168.100.54"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "192.168.100.53",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "96",
    "Ls id": "1.1.1.1",
    "chksum": "0x16fc",
    "Adv rtr": "1.1.1.1",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "6"
  }
]
```

Expected to have result as below

```
[
  {
    "type": "Router",
    "sID": "1.1.1.2",
    "dID": "1.1.1.2",
    "LinkType":"StubNet",
    "Metric":"1"
  },
  { 
    "type": "Router",
    "sID": "1.1.1.2", 
    "dID": "1.1.1.4",
    "Link Type": "P-2-P",
    "Metric": "1"
  },
  {
    "type": "Router",
    "sID": "1.1.1.2",
    "dID": "192.168.100.33",
    "LinkType":"StubNet",
    "Metric":"1"   
  },   
  { 
    "type": "Router",     
    "sID": "1.1.1.2",     
    "dID":"1.1.1.1",
    "Link Type": "P-2-P",
    "Metric": "1"
  },
  {
    "type": "Router",
    "sID": "1.1.1.1",
    "dID": "1.1.1.1",     
    "LinkType":"StubNet",     
    "Metric":"1"  
   },   
   {     
    "type": "Router",
    "sID": "1.1.1.1",
    "dID":"1.1.1.1",
    "Link Type": "StubNet",
    "Metric": "12"
  },
  {
    "type": "Router",
    "sID": "1.1.1.1",
    "dID": "1.1.1.3",
    "LinkType":"P-2-P",
    "Metric":"10"   
  } 
]
```

Appreciate to advise how could proceed further. I have search around and try error and still no able to resolve it. Appreciate your advise and support. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to iterate over devices and then over device['items']

```
import json

with open('source.json', 'r') as ifile:
    json_data=json.load(ifile)

my_result=[]

for device in json_data:
    for item in device.get('items', []):
        my_dict={}
        my_dict['type'] = device.get('Type')
        my_dict['sID'] = device.get('Ls id')
        my_dict['dID'] = item.get('Link ID')
        my_dict['Link Type'] = item.get('Link Type')
        my_dict['Metric'] = item.get('Metric')
        my_result.append(my_dict)

with open('extract.json', 'w') as ofile:
    json.dump(my_result, ofile, indent=4)
```

For more structured code you may want to define a function(s) that takes device/item as argument, parse it and return a list of dicts/dict

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the values like a dictionary, for example:

```
ifile=open('source.json', 'r')
ofile=open('extract.json', 'w')
json_decode=json.load(ifile)
myresult=[]
for item in json_decode:
    mydict={}
    mydict['sID']=item['Ls id']
    my_dict['dID']=item['items']['Link ID']['Metric']['Link Type']
    mydict['type']=item['Type']
    myresult.append(mydict)
myjson=json.dumps(myresult, ofile)
ofile.write(myjson)
ofile.close()
```

Does this work for you? If not, what errors are you running into?

Comment: Hi sir..thank you for your response and help... I'm getting error mydict['dID']=item['items']['Link ID']['Metric']['Link Type']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 1):

First, you are getting a list in `item['items']`. You need to decide whether you need to save all values available inside that list or not.

Second, you are trying to access multiple attributes in a dict at once, but you're chaining the `get` commands. The code however attempts to treat it like a nested dict, and would run into datatype errors.

Third, you don't actually need to type `get` like that, a cleaner version is to just use the square bracket notation.

Assuming you need to create a new dict for each of the items in the list of `item['items']` a solution would look something like this:

```
import json
s = '''
[
  {
    "Ls age": "201",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.2",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.4",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "192.168.100.34"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "192.168.100.33",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.1",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "192.168.100.53"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "84",
    "Ls id": "1.1.1.2",
    "Adv rtr": "1.1.1.2",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Link count": "5"
  },
  {
    "Ls age": "1699",
    "seq#": "80008d72",
    "items": [
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.1",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "1",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.1",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "12",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.3",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "192.168.100.26"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "192.168.100.25",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "1.1.1.2",
        "Link Type": "P-2-P",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "192.168.100.54"
      },
      {
        "Link ID": "192.168.100.53",
        "Link Type": "StubNet",
        "Metric": "10",
        "Data": "255.255.255.255",
        "Priority": "Medium"
      }
    ],
    "Len": "96",
    "Ls id": "1.1.1.1",
    "chksum": "0x16fc",
    "Adv rtr": "1.1.1.1",
    "Type": "Router",
    "Options": "ASBR  E",
    "Link count": "6"
  }
]
'''
input_lst = json.loads(s)
myresult=[]
for item in input_lst:
    mydict={}
    mydict_sID = item['Ls id']
    mydict_type = item['Type']
    temp = []
    for x in item['items']:
        mydict={'Ls id': mydict_sID,
                'Type': mydict_type,
                'Link ID': x['Link ID'],
                'Metric': x['Metric'],
                'Link Type': x['Link Type']
                }
        temp.append(mydict)
    myresult.extend(temp)
```

Make sure you change the code lines that i used to read the string as necessary.

Comment: Thank you sir for provide my the guideline and changes to the code. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `item['items']` is also a list so you need an inner loop to process all of its elements. Furthermore you must extract individually each value:

```
for item in json_decode:
    for sub in item.get('items'):
        mydict={}
        mydict['type']=item.get('Type')
        mydict['sID']=item.get('Ls id')
        mydict['dID']=sub.get('Link ID')
        mydict['Link Type']=sub.get('Link Type')
        mydict['Metric']=sub.get('Metric')
        myresult.append(mydict)
```

Answer (score 1):

to process the elements of a nested object of the list, you need to use an additional loop, for example,

```
import json

ifile = 'source.json'
ofile = 'extract.json'

myresult = []
with open(ifile, 'r') as sf:
   json_decode = json.load(sf)
   for item in json_decode:
       for sub_item in item.get('items', []):
           myresult.append(dict(type=item.get('Type'),
                                sID=item.get('Ls id', ''),
                                dID=sub_item.get('Link ID'),
                                LinkType=sub_item.get('Link Type'),
                                Metric=sub_item.get('Metric')
                                )
                           )

with open(ofile, 'w') as of:
    of.write(json.dumps(myresult, indent=4))
```

or a slightly abbreviated version using list comprehension:

```
import json

ifile = 'source.json'
ofile = 'extract.json'

with open(ifile, 'r') as sf:
    json_decode = json.load(sf)
    myresult = [dict(type=item.get('Type'), 
                     sID=item.get('Ls id', ''), 
                     dID=sub_item.get('Link ID'),
                     LinkType=sub_item.get('Link Type'), 
                     Metric=sub_item.get('Metric')) for item in json_decode 
                for sub_item in item.get('items', [])]

with open(ofile, 'w') as of:
    of.write(json.dumps(myresult, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Both is a good solution for my case and it does work. Thanks for sharing and i appreciate this.